# ¿Por qué es necesario de utilizar Apache o Nginx para una app en python?

Tags: python, webservice, deployment

Por que las aplicaciones escritas en python y tambien he visto en nodejs necesitan algo como Apache o Nginx?

Comment: para aclarar la pregunta por la otra respuesta (en comentario no cabría, ;-D ), te refieres a aplicaciones web?

Comment: No lo necesitan. Podes escribir un simple **hello world** en NodeJS por ejemplo y iniciar la app. Vas a poder acceder al recurso sin necesidad ni de Apache ni de Nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Se recomienda por performance, los servidores web como los que mencionas están optimizados para tareas como la descarga de archivos, redirección, manejo de headers como eTag o expires.

Ningún servidor de aplicaciones puede atender la misma cantidad de peticiones por segundo que el webserver en sí, principalmente porque está ejecutando precisamente la lógica de los servicios dinámicos.

Entonces, requerido no es, puedes poner por ejemplo un servicio en node, php, python, tomcat o lo que quieras a manejar todas las peticiones, pero su rendimiento será netamente inferior.

Answer (score 0):

Mal redactada la pregunta porque ningún lenguaje requiere un servidor web. Es un protocolo más de todos los disponibles y dependerá exclusivamente de tu aplicación o script.

Un script o binario genera, finalmente, y para lo que creo sugieres, un documento. Si quieres que este sea publicado en una web debes usar un servidor web. Si quieres cargarle en un servidor FTP debes enviarlo a ese servidor. Luego los servidores, mediante el protocolo que usen, lo ponen a disposición de los clientes.

Con lo anterior claro. Se requiere un servidor (web, ftp, correo, etc) para que a través de aquel sea distribuido. Y la razón de que lo haga un script o binario es porque el cliente no puede hacerlo ya sea que no posee la información, la técnica/herramientas o la capacidad necesarias.

Por ejemplo usando Python, PHP, BASH, etc. puedes acceder a los recursos (archivos, base de datos, servicios externos o internos, otros scripts, etc) del servidor, producir un resultado en forma de documento HTML y este, mediante el protocolo HTTP ponerle a disposición del público.